# customize alert box angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a login form I make a test if the username & password invalid I want showed in sweet alert

this is my code :

```
 else {
          alert('login & password invalid')
          var path = "index.html";
          window.location.href = path;
         }
```

this is link of my plunker : [link plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iT4ZVUaFktE7Lso7SFYU?p=preview)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

My opinion, it's easier just to make a div that has an absolute positioning in the center of the screen, make the size, colors, words whatever you want.  Make the display invisible.

Then, add a JS event listener to make it visible whenever you need it to be.  I built a web phone app where the editing forms were positioned overlapped of the main project in the center of the screen, made visible/invisible by events.

Also, don't forget to add box-shadow ;)

Comment: Just create a div box, make it the right size you want with %'s, position the margins to make it on the screen where you want it, you want it to over-lap everything. Set position to absolute. Then, make no display, and whatever triggers it, give it an event listener that makes it show, it'll give the same effect alert does, and give it box shadow too!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a modal popup for which there are many different options.

Look at [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#api).

You can create a custom HTML template that will display your login alert window, then in your code call

```
else {
    ngDialog.open({
        template: 'externalTemplate.html',
        controller: 'SomeController'
    });
}
```